# In what way should we map a proto message with a oneof to a dataclass with clean code

Tags: flutter, dart, protocol-buffers

We are working on a flutter application and we use the grpc protocol with proto for our datasource. Some of our messages (particularly responses) have oneof's. I was somewhat confused how we could map this to my own dataclass while still having clean code.

So as an example we have the following proto message

```
message ComponentProperties {
    oneof properties{
        Sprite sprite = 1;
        Text text = 2;
        Music music = 3;
        SoundEffect soundEffect = 4;
        Spritesheet spritesheet = 5;
    }
}
```

The idea is that for one of the messages in the `oneof` we would draw some ui.

The model that we found would fit very naturally is below.

```
class ComponentProperties {
  final Sprite? sprite;
  final Music? music;
  final SoundEffect? soundEffect;
  final Spritesheet? spritesheet;
  final Text? text;

  bool get hasSprite => sprite != null;
  bool get hasMusic => music != null;
  bool get hasSoundEffect => soundEffect != null;
  bool get hasSpritesheet => spritesheet != null;
  bool get hasText => text != null;

  const ComponentProperties({
    this.sprite,
    this.music,
    this.soundEffect,
    this.spritesheet,
    this.text,
  });

  ComponentProperties copyWith({
    Sprite? sprite,
    Music? music,
    SoundEffect? soundEffect,
    Spritesheet? spritesheet,
    Text? text,
  }) {
    return ComponentProperties(
      sprite: sprite ?? this.sprite,
      music: music ?? this.music,
      soundEffect: soundEffect ?? this.soundEffect,
      spritesheet: spritesheet ?? this.spritesheet,
      text: text ?? this.text,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{
      'sprite': sprite?.toMap(),
      'music': music?.toMap(),
      'soundEffect': soundEffect?.toMap(),
      'spritesheet': spritesheet?.toMap(),
      'text': text?.toMap(),
    };
    map.removeWhere((key, value) => value == null);
    return map;
  }

  factory ComponentProperties.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ComponentProperties(
      sprite: map['sprite'] != null
          ? Sprite.fromMap((map["sprite"] ?? Map<String, dynamic>.from({})) as Map<String, dynamic>)
          : null,
      music: map['music'] != null
          ? Music.fromMap((map["music"] ?? Map<String, dynamic>.from({})) as Map<String, dynamic>)
          : null,
      soundEffect: map['soundEffect'] != null
          ? SoundEffect.fromMap(
              (map["soundEffect"] ?? Map<String, dynamic>.from({})) as Map<String, dynamic>)
          : null,
      spritesheet: map['spritesheet'] != null
          ? Spritesheet.fromMap(
              (map["spritesheet"] ?? Map<String, dynamic>.from({})) as Map<String, dynamic>)
          : null,
      text: map['text'] != null
          ? Text.fromMap((map["text"] ?? Map<String, dynamic>.from({})) as Map<String, dynamic>)
          : null,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory ComponentProperties.fromJson(String source) =>
      ComponentProperties.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);

  proto.ComponentProperties toProto() =>
      proto.ComponentProperties.create()..mergeFromProto3Json(toMap());

  factory ComponentProperties.fromProto(proto.ComponentProperties source) =>
      ComponentProperties.fromMap(source.toProto3Json() as Map<String, dynamic>);

  ComponentProperties merge(ComponentProperties other) =>
      ComponentProperties.fromMap(mergeMaps(toMap(), other.toMap()));

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'ComponentProperties(sprite: $sprite, music: $music, soundEffect: $soundEffect, spritesheet: $spritesheet, text: $text)';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant ComponentProperties other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other.sprite == sprite &&
        other.music == music &&
        other.soundEffect == soundEffect &&
        other.spritesheet == spritesheet &&
        other.text == text;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    return sprite.hashCode ^
        music.hashCode ^
        soundEffect.hashCode ^
        spritesheet.hashCode ^
        text.hashCode;
  }
}
```

But this would lead to writing switch statements where we want to draw UI.

We could also make an interface like so

```
abstract class ComponentProperties {
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap();
  String toJson();
  factory ComponentProperties.fromProtoMap(
    Map<String, dynamic> map,
  ) {
    final entry = map.entries.first;
    final entryMap = Map<String, dynamic>.fromEntries([
      entry,
    ]);
    switch (entry.key) {
      case Sprite.name:
        return Sprite.fromProtoMap(entryMap);
      case Music.name:
        return Music.fromProtoMap(entryMap);
      case SoundEffect.name:
        return SoundEffect.fromProtoMap(entryMap);
      case Spritesheet.name:
        return Spritesheet.fromProtoMap(entryMap);
      case Text.name:
        return Text.fromProtoMap(entryMap);
      default:
        throw Exception('component with type ${map['type']} unknown');
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toProtoMap();
}
```

Which would allow us to have a factory that creates the resource one time. And use polymorphism with something like a draw method to create a widget. So a class named Sprite for example would implement this interface.

Because of how protobuf works it will give you an object with the key being the one from the `oneof`. For example

```
{
  sprite: {
    ...
  }
}
```

And then there are some disadvantages.

We would need something like `map.entries.first` to get the actual resource that was recieved because we don't know what the one in `oneof` is. But only when we map from and to proto.

You can't override `copyWith` because each resource has different properties, so you can't call `properties.copyWith()`.

We would need different mapping for proto specifically because the map contains an object that has a key that represents the type. This usually leads to someone using `toMap` when generating code where toProtoMap should be used and causes bugs.

And we would use polymorphism to draw the widget. This would mean that we would implement draw methods in our dataclasses in order to render anything to the screen. I haven't really seen other Flutter projects do this. The ones I have seen usually only have import from the data layer into the presentation layer and not the other way around. It would mean we need to import widgets in our dataclasses.

This also means we couldn't have these dataclasses in an all dart package that is a dependency of multiple flutter packages. We would need to import material so we would need to make it a flutter package. And we would need to have the presentation logic in this dependency package. Even though we want to render different UI in the flutter packages that this package is a dependency of. We also wouldn't be able to for example override the draw method in those flutter packages because the dataclass is in the dependency package. So we would we would have to maintain the same dataclasses in each flutter project so we can implement the draw method there. Which also causes a lot of maintenance.

So the first approach seems to be more in line and natural with the oneof and flutter architecture. The proto code generated also has the fields as nullable. Which makes mapping more natural. But it goes against clean code. And will cause switch statements each time we want to draw something.

So my question is could we approach this so we have clean code that also still feels natural with protobuf, allows you to copy the dataclass easily and is in line with flutter architecture?

Because it almost feels like we have to choose between these two options and they both have their disadvantages. I would say we would only render a widget in one place for this dataclass. But we have to copy the dataclass many times. And there is also code generated which has already caused multiple errors because it defaults to toMap. Which makes the first model seem much more attractive.

But in the future we might want to render widgets in different places which would make the switch statements unmaintainable.

Comment: Wow... Have you considered writing a PhD on this?  Anyway, hope you find your answer.

Comment: Have you looked at the [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) package? It has many of the features you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it there are multiple possible objects coming from one request. And depending on what the request gives you, you want to draw different ui. This is somewhat difficult to make with clean code. I would recommend a `enum` that keeps all the switch stuff out of your code without using direct polymorphism, because that itself is against flutter code style:

```dart
enum ComponentPropertiesType<T> {
  sprite(Sprite.fromJson),
  music(Music.fromJson),
  sound(SoundEffect.fromJson),
  spriteSheet(SpriteSheet.fromJson),
  text(Text.fromJson);

  static ComponentPropertiesType fromProtoMap(Map<String, dynamic> protoMap) {
    assert(protoMap.keys.length == 1);
    var key = protoMap.keys.first;

    return ComponentPropertiesType.values.firstWhere(
      (element) => element.name == key,
      orElse: () {
        throw Exception("Component $key unknown");
      }
    );
  }

  final T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json) fromJson;
  const ComponentPropertiesType(this.fromJson);

  Type get genericType => T;
}

class Sprite {
  factory Sprite.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
class Music {
  factory Music.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
class SoundEffect {
  factory SoundEffect.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
class SpriteSheet {
  factory SpriteSheet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
class Text {
  factory Text.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

I believe this is by far the best code style possible. Why?:

- Any item in the enum clearly says what type it is returning, by using the method genericType anyone can get what this thing is going to be
- Any item has a fromJson or similar method that return an instance of what it is going to be,
- No switch statements
- O(n) runtime of the fromProtoMap method
- No limitations on the classes

Now, one problem remains to be solved: How to avoid switch statements all over the widgets in the ui without importing flutter and thus making it a flutter-dependend libary?
Solution: Extensions! In the UI part where it is not a problem to have Flutter, we do this:

```dart
extension GetWidgetForType on ComponentPropertiesType {
  Widget getWidget() {
    switch (runtimeType) {
      case ...
    }
  }
}
```

Now to be fair, there is one switch statement here. But that is only one. And I dont think that is a bad thing. So that would be my solution

Comment: Love your idea of extensions in the presentation layer. For the properties I went a different route. Since I use clean architecture I ended up writing a mapper for my data models to my entity. So my data model would have a .toEntity() returning the entity. That way I can still use polymorphism for a draw method with the extension you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact inner-workings of grpc (I am not all that familiar with it) and your specific problem exactly, this sounds like a perfect use case for union typing. [Dart does not have support for union typing out of the box](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1222); however, it can be achieved on your own with some fancy (but verbose) polymorphism (if you want, I can edit this with an example) or with a code generation tool like [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) that automates all of that boilerplate for you (and which I would highly recommend).

In [freezed with union types](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#union-types-and-sealed-classes), all of this would look something like:

```dart
part 'component_piece.freezed.dart';
class ComponentPiece with _$ComponentPiece {
  const ComponentPiece._();
  const factory ComponentPiece.sprite(Sprite sprite) = SpriteComponentPiece;
  const factory ComponentPiece.music(Music music) = MusicComponentPiece;
  const factory ComponentPiece.soundEffect(SoundEffect soundEffect) = SoundEffectComponentPiece;
  const factory ComponentPiece.spritesheet(Spritesheet spritesheet) = SpritesheetComponentPiece;
  const factory ComponentPiece.text(Text text) = TextComponentPiece;

  factory ComponentPiece.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    // TODO return a ComponentPiece created from one of the other constructors above using the map
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return when(
      sprite: (sprite) => {'sprite': sprite.toMap()},
      music: (music) => {'music': music.toMap()},
      soundEffect: (soundEffect) => {'soundEffect': soundEffect.toMap()},
      spritesheet: (spritesheet) => {'spriteSheet': spriteSheet.toMap()},
      text: (text) => {'text': text.toMap()},
    );
  }

  // Worth mentioning: freezed supports toJson() and fromJson() methods,
  //  but those need some special care with an extra "runtimeType" field in the Map in order to work
  // Since it seemed like with grpc you had your own serialization system going on, I excluded that aspect of freezed here
  // You can read more about what I am talking about here:
  // https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#fromjsontojson
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```dart
// Notice how the type of component is just a ComponentPiece
//  (think of ComponentPiece as "one of" sprite, music, soundEffect, etc.)
// You could also simply do:
//  final component = SpriteComponentPiece(someSprite);
// because SpriteComponentPiece is a class created by freezed for you.
ComponentPiece component = ComponentPiece.sprite(someSprite);

// Here's the fun part:
component.when(
  sprite: (sprite) => doSomethingWithSprite(sprite),
  music: (music) => doSomethingWithMusic(music),
  soundEffect: (soundEffect) => doSomethingWithSoundEffect(soundEffect),
  spritesheet: (spritesheet) => doSomethingWithSpriteSheet(spritesheet),
  text: (text) => doSomethingWithText(text),
);
```

[`.when()`](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#when) and [`.map()`](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#map) can both seem a little daunting at first, but are extremely powerful (think switch-cases on steroids). In your case, if trying to create a widget based on a component piece, you can do something like:

```dart
// This example uses https://pub.dev/packages/functional_widget
//  because it is far easier to define Widgets with it
// This example also assumes SpriteWidget, MusicWidget, etc. are defined somewhere and all take one positional argument of their data

part 'component_piece_widget.g.dart';

@swidget
Widget _componentPieceWidget(ComponentPiece component) {
  return component.when(
    sprite: SpriteWidget,
    music: MusicWidget,
    soundEffect: SoundEffectWidget,
    spritesheet: SpriteSheetWidget,
    text: TextWidget,
  );
}
```

This will automatically create the widget of the correct type given a `ComponentPiece`.